# How to Extract an Element using XPathSelectElement

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xsd

I am extracting an element from an xml document but it's returning `null`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test1 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-test"
   xmlns="https://www.google.com/partner/testt.xsd">

  <Test2>OK</Test2>
  <Test3>1439379003</Test3>
</Test1>
```

I'm trying to extract `test2` element but its returning `null`

```
var responseXdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
var statusElement = responseXdoc.XPathSelectElement("/Test1/Test2");
```

result `statusElement` as `null` but I'm expecting `Ok`

**Problem in Namespace**

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="https://www.google.com/partner/testt.xsd (Its my guess)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace which elements in the scope inherit implicitly. To reference elements in namespace using XPath, you need to use namespace prefix which, you need to register before in an `XmlNamespaceManager` :

```
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "https://www.insuranceleads.com/partner/PricePresentationResult.xsd");

var statusElement = responseXdoc.XPathSelectElement("/d:Test1/d:Test2", nsManager);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pgv3DO)</kbd>**

Alternatively, you can use `XNamespace` and LINQ API to do the same, for example :

```
XNamespace d = "https://www.insuranceleads.com/partner/PricePresentationResult.xsd";
var statusElement = responseXdoc.Element(d + "Test1").Element(d + "Test2");
```